# Mysites Configuration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, mysite, farm, sharepoint-farm

I have configured the following service applications
a) MMS
b) search
c) user profile

I have created a web application at http://server which is at port 80 and also a team site collection here.

do I need to create another web application for Mysites at a different port e.g.
http://server:1000  and set the host header to mysites
Or Can I add another web Application at port 80 and set a separate hostheader.

Is there any example for Host header for Mysites .

Do I need to change the bindings in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create site collction of type My Site host. and conceptually you have to configure host header as same as you configure for Team site. (Make sure that at differenet port, http://server:1000, my site host should be root site)